# Startup Problem 2.79

Tags: startup-file

Why there is Startup Problem 2.79. Im getting problem with 2.79 new version i have downloaded. The installation done successfully. When i click on the exe the cmd run and disappears and nothing happens. Blender did not launch. Im using 64bit setup but when i tried the 32bit zip its working. So whats the problem why Blender is not getting start with the installation. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

**On command line this is the error**

[image]

Comment: assuming you're on windows 64bit, try opening a console, then launch blender form the command line (if you installed it to the c:\ unit, it should be something like "c:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender.exe". In this way you can see if there are messages showing errors, to understand what's happening. Did you try a 64bit zip also?

Comment: @m.ardito i have attach the error screenshot

Comment: to me it sounds like an issue with your hardware with how that setup installed the 64bit (you didn't say if a 64bit zip works), maybe some OS issue is creating this error, not blender. In this thread (https://developer.blender.org/T43840) the user had the same exact error, try if something suggested works, and then maybe submit your issue as a bug...

Comment: @m.ardito with the zip and .exe same issue. Before blender was working good. once i have installed pip and shapely for archipack 2d and it got error and to remove that pip and shapely i uninstall blender and install. But from that it never start.

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: @dr.Sybren yes 64 bit win 7.

Comment: In that case, sendin a bug report at https://developer.blender.org/. Make sure you fill out all the details.

Comment: Downloading the .zip file has fixed the problem for me.